# Where can I find parallel processing implementation in the latest version of Hyperledger Sawtooth?

Tags: blockchain, scheduler, hyperledger-sawtooth

We have worked on a parallel scheduling implementation for hyperledger sawtooth and want to compare it's performance with the existing parallel scheduling implementation in sawtooth.
For v1.2, we've found the existing implementation of the parallel scheduler in
"sawtooth-core/validator/sawtooth_validator/execution/scheduler_parallel.py" and worked with it, but are unable to find the analogous location of parallel implementation of the scheduler in the latest version of Sawtooth.
Could anyone help us out with the location of the parallel scheduler, or tell if it is using the same python file for parallel implementation by calling the same methods and passing converted objects from the rust files in the present implementation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.